# Java API to fill form in a program, which resides in remote desktop?

Tags: java, copy, desktop, paste

If someone could point me in the right direction by telling me whether this can even be done or not. I would like to create another program which automatically updates the fields in another program. Just like automatic form filling on browsers, except this does it in the other program. One of the caveats, is that this other program (in which the form resides in) is being run in a remote desktop environment, will this affect the program I make, in any way?

- In other words:-

Can I make a program that reads whats on screen?
If I click a button on the said program that I have created, it will fill all the fields in the form(not a browser, but a local program); which is currently on the screen; automatically from a predefined xml file?

- All in all, I am trying to make a glorified copy and paste program...

Comment: Yes this can definitely be done, I assume the program you wish to alter is not written by you, is it written in Java though? What kind of access do you have to this remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

With library `JNativeHook` you can catch all events (keyboard,mouse) without having a focus. And to new events into System Event Queue you can user `Robot` class